# Finding Recurrence Relation in Closed Form or as Infinite Summation/Coproduct

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations

My recurrence relation is:

$$f(n)=(2n-3) f(n-1) -x^2 f(n-2)$$

Where

$$f(-1)=1$$
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f(1)=-x^2$$
$$f(2)=f(1)$$
$$f(3)=-x^2 (3-x^2)$$

And it gets more complicated from there